# How to decleare char *const argv[] in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a c style array of chars pointer like this:

```
*const argv[]
```

I figured out i have to use `UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>`

but i don't know how to initialize it.

How can i map this normal Array to `UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>` :

```
let argv = ["/usr/bin/printf", "BBB"]
```

Thank you

Comment: This is invalid `*const argv[] `, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @iharob Run this function ==> public func execvp(_: UnsafePointer<Int8>, _: UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>) -> Int32

Comment: @iharob execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);

Comment: @Olaf I remove the tag

Comment: @iAdjunct This question has nothing to do about argv & argc it's something different. I'm trying to create an array with char pointers. Not duplicate.

Comment: Ahhh, misinterpreted that.

Comment: @iAdjunct It's okay ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to let Cocoa form the C strings for you:

```
let args = ["/usr/bin/printf","BBB"]
var cs = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>.alloc(2)
for (ix,s) in args.enumerate() {
    cs[ix] = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>((s as NSString).UTF8String)
}
var cs2 : UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> = UnsafePointer(cs)
```

Beware; `cs` does not contain copies. Its pointers are pointing right into the strings in `args`.

Comment: Thank you @matt , but i need UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> not a UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>> . UnsafePointer doesn't have alloc , UnsafeMutablePointer has. can you explain me how to make a UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> with this method ?

Comment: `let cs2 : UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>> = UnsafePointer(cs)`

Comment: Why do you want to make the inner pointers mutable? In C strings, they are not.

Comment: I want to use a posix function in unistd :
public func execvp(_: UnsafePointer<Int8>, _: UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>) -> Int32

Comment: Okay, I wrote it all out for you, but this is absolutely the last time. :)

Comment: Thank you very much !! I find out UnsafePointer has a constructor that gives a UnsafeMutablePointer. Your answers are very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, but I warn you again, it makes no sense with the code I've written to make the CStrings mutable. We are pointing into the Strings; you cannot mutate these.